# TCP protocol mystery

Tags: ipv4, pcap

I am attempting to compile, with pcap-filter, the following string:

```
host yb-in-f91.1e100.n
```

Obtained from the following command:

```
netstat -t

output line: tcp 0 0 os-info:portnum yb-in-f91.1e100.n
```

However, `libpcap` complains that this is not a valid ip protocol:

```
pcap_compile: unknown host 'yb-in-f91.1e100.n'
```

Are there special options or is there a conversion I need to do for `libpcap` to understand this address?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about programming are off-topic here. You can ask about programming on [so], where there are many network-savvy programmers.

Comment: IP and subsequently TCP *always* use IP addresses. If those cannot be resolved from a host name you use, *nothing* works. DNS is just an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any special options to libpcap to understand the address because it's very unlikely that it's a valid one.

However if you use netstat -tW so that you don't truncate the address in the first place, you will probably have more success.

Comment: It makes sense as a question, because I submitted an unmodified string that, very clearly, is not a plain-text 123.123.123.123 style IP-Address.  Adding `tW` fixed the problem. Nonetheless, the ip-address submitted from the `netstat` address column is **still not** a 1.1.1.1 style ip address string.  So there does appear to be a degree of freedom here that I needed to negotiate with a setting.  The setting was a `netstat` setting, and not a `libpcap` setting.  Nonetheless, the answer was to change a setting.

Comment: And, of all of the problems in computer science and engineering, arbitrary setting changes are the hardest to answer -- they typically require a brute force perusal of documentation.  So I appreciate this answer, and stack overflow as a resource for this type of question and answer.